# Create bars on side of a matriz on python

Tags: python, matrix, element

I want to make a matriz nxn but on the vertical sides I want to put "|" but I can't do it with the code below:

```
def creatematriz(nlines, ncoluns, valor):
    M = []
    for i in range(nlines):
        line = []
        for j in range(ncoluns):
            line.append(valor)
        M.append(line)
    return M
def printMatriz(matriz):
    for line in matriz:
        for position in line:
            print(position, end=" ")
        print("|")
def main():
    m=creatematriz(20,6,'0')
    printMatriz(m)
main()
```

I want something like this:

```
| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
```

But I only get:

```
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Kudos for posting a good example.  For `creatematriz()`, try using python "list comprehensions":  `M = [ [0 for i in range(ncoluns)] for j in range(nlines)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `printMatriz` function to print a `|` before the inner loop:

```
def printMatriz(matriz):
    for line in matriz:
        print("|", end="")
        for position in line:
            print(position, end=" ")
        print("|")
```

Comment: Thanks. But now the print is:     
|
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
|
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
|
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 |
i mean the bar( | ) stay on the zero instead beside

Comment: Try `print(" |")` for the last line.

Comment: @VictorKamia - To show thanks, please select the answer (click the checkmark).  In addition to adding to the poster's reputation, it also shows everyone that the question is answered to your satisfaction (when they're looking for questions to help with.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using only one loop and the `join` function:

```
def printMatriz(matriz):
    for line in matriz:
        print("| " + " ".join(line) + " | ")
```